# CustomPopup not working Safari , JRE 1.7 Mac OS

Tags: macos, safari, java, java-7, browser-plugin

I'm not sure if the problem is with my code or with JRE 1.7 plugin for Safari with Mac OS , as custom popup doesn't seems to be working in the above mentioned combination

But when we try to make a server call to populate data in a custom popup in the Custom combo box extended by JComboBox it flashes the popup for some micro seconds and then disappears .

The same code works fine JRE 1.6 plugin for Safari with Mac OS and also JRE 1.7 , JRE 1.6 plugin for IE with Windows OS .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to roll back 1.7 to 1.6.  Apple has made damn well sure you can not go back easily.  I have tried every fix on the net.  Nothing works.  In terminal java -version stubbornly shows 1.7.  I have seen no way other than to reload OS X.